# Is there any implementation in `stim` that takes correlated edges into consideration?

Tags: stim

When we decode X/Z graph separately, we didn't consider about the correlation between this two graphs. There are some techniques like reweighting X/Z graphs recursively to explain the correlation induced by Y errors.

**My Question:** Is there any implementation in `stim` to do this kind of **correlation analysis** stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call [`stim.Circuit.detector_error_model`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/wiki/Stim-v1.8-Python-API-Reference#stim.Circuit.detector_error_model) to extract a matching graph from an annotated circuit, you can add the argument `decompose_errors=True`. This will add "suggested decompositions" to errors. For example, an error mechanism like `error(0.1) D5 D10 D11` might become `error(0.1) D5 ^ D10 D11`. In the case of an XZ surface code, the suggested decomposition for a Y error will be to decompose it into the X and Z parts.

This is only half the story, though. The decoder consuming the error model is ultimately responsible for using these suggested decompositions to improve decoding. As far as I know, PyMatching doesn't do correlated decoding. But maybe you have access to a decoder that does. In which case you could write glue code that turns the suggested decompositions into correlation update rules for that decoder.